# Using route filters in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I'm trying to use route filters in laravel to check whether a specific user has an access to a page:

```
Route::filter('check_roles', function()
{
    $current_url = URI::current();
    $access = 0;
    $nav = Session::get('navigation');
    foreach($nav as $k => $n){
      if(in_array($current_url, $n)){
        $access = 1;
      }
    }

    if($access == 0){
     return Redirect::to('home');
    }
    //problem is if the user has access to the page a blank page is returned

});
```

I'm using it in a route like this:

```
Route::get('admin/(:all)', array('before' => 'check_roles'));
```

The problem is if the user has access to the page a blank page is returned. How do I continue on with the default controller action if the user has access?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `Route::get()` with `Route::filter('pattern: admin/*', 'check_roles');`.

Now every time a request contains this pattern will be calling your check_roles filter.
I think that this is what you currently need and not a `Route::get()`,

You could use `Route::get()` on individual pages like

`Route::get('supersecret', array('before' => 'check_roles'), function()
 { return View::make('mysecret') });`

For more info [Routing - Filters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#filters)

Updating to reflect my suggestion on the comment.

You can create an `Admin_Controller` that will extends your `Base_Controller` and have your auth filter in the `__construct()`.

```
class Admin_Controller extends Base_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->filter('before', 'auth');
    }
}
```

Have this contoller registered in your start.php (search for Autoloader, where your base_controller is mapped).

And you could now extends your `Admin_Controller` whenever you want to protected your area.

```
class Pages_Controller extends Admin_Controller {
    // do cool stuff
 }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm doing route::filter with the auth filter. When I tried doing something like this: Route::filter('pattern: admin/*', 'auth|check_roles'); it only executes the first one.

Comment: I think maybe the problem here is that laravel isn't executing the method that I have in the controller so its doing nothing. I've already use Route::controller(Controller::detect()); to create a route for every controller but it doesn't seem to be taking effect.

Comment: Multiple filters can be attached in REST routes, i dont think you can create a filter that uses multiple filters. What you might need is to create a new Controller and attach to that your Controller your auth filter. Then extends that Controller whenever you need your users to provide a password for accessing that part of your app

Comment: Route::controller(Controller::detect()) it been reported that it screws up the routes, i suggest you manually add the controllers you need to be routed like, `Route::controller(array('admin', 'members', pages', 'and_so_on'));`

Comment: thanks! I've just included the check_roles filter using ```Route::filter('admin/*', 'check_roles')``` and the ```auth``` filter on the controller.